# Using JSF instead of JSP in WebApplication in IDEA

Tags: java, jsf, intellij-idea

I am geting used to be Java programmer, and I've just taught servlets. But IDEA ctreates index.jsp, when I choose "Create Web Application". I've run into one article where found out from about JSF. It was described as a better and newest version of WebApp desiging.
I've written a project where index.jsp are used (web->src->main->webapp) inside this path. It was created by IDEA. Now I wanna substitude JSP with XHTML. I've done it, assebled my project and deployed. But when I go to

```
localhost:8080/web/
```

I see nothing. When I use "index.JSP", I can see content of my JSP-page. Please, help me to correct my project. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make JSF working, you have some configuration to do:

- Make sure you have a faces-config.xml at the same level as WEB-INF folder, containing this for JSF 2.0:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

- JSF uses a servlet provided by Java EE, javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet. You must add some elements into your web.xml, to declare this servlet:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Using this configuration, you must put your JSF at the same level as WEB-INF and give them the extension .xhtml. Of course you can set the pattern.

JSF is not only make to replace JSF files. This is a big framework which allow you to write only the business logic. You will need to learn more about JSF before using it. Take a look [right here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/).

Comment: hah)) I am just exactly looking throught this article. I've done what is written there, particularly what you've said, but it is still not working = (

Comment: I've even added dependecies iinto pom.xml. But nothing is going right = (

Comment: What happens if you go to localhost:8080/web/index.xhtml? If it works, make sure index.xhtml is defined as a welcome file into your web.xml

Comment: hah))) you're reading my actions) are you a spy? nothing is working = ( I've done it before read your response

Comment: aaa... sorry, I was mistaken! It works now! Thanks a lot! Listen, what did you say about web.xml? How can I change localhost:8080/WEB/ in web.xml? F.e. I want to see my page on localhost:8080/MAINSERVER/index.xhtml?

Comment: This is a configuration of your application server. [The display-name of web.xml is useless for that](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1043408).